# Can I assign values to null-initialized properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null, initialization, phpstorm, type-mismatch

I am creating a JavaScript object and I'd like to be able to distinguish between unset and empty properties. Therefore I initialize it's properties to `null` at creation. Then I can fill the properties with specific values. Sometimes these values are empty (such as `''` for string properties and 0 for numbers). I have something like this:

```
var myObject = {
    aString: null,

    setEmpty() {
        this.aString = '';
    }     
}
```

I am programming with PhpStorm, and it complains: "Assigned expression type string is not assignable to type null". AFAIK, `null` is a special object type in JavaScript, so I am facing a type mismatch problem. But how can I otherwise tell an empty value from an uninitialized one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, since JavaScript is weak typing

Comment: Don't I violate some good practice when doing so? Does using `"use strict";` change anything in that respect?

Comment: no, you don't violate any best practices, dynamic typing is a language feature

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is weakly, dynamically typed. You can absolutely do that. The error reported by PHPStorm is not valid for JavaScript.

Comment: Don't I violate some good practice when doing so? Does using `"use strict";` change anything in that respect?

Comment: @texnic this is all trivially testable. Plug it into JSFiddle or ever your browser's console and you can see for yourself.

Comment: I obviously have tested it already, my program works fine. I just want to understand why PhpStorm (which knows that I am writing with JS) reports it as an error.

Comment: Nothing is obvious on SO. The reason PHPStorm reports an error is because you are using a PHP IDE to write JavaScript.

Comment: The same flavor of error manifests in WebStorm, which is definitely a Javascript IDE. It doesn't seem at all like a valid warning (it is a 'weak warning' by default) in Javascript. Maybe this is a bug of some sort, the JetBrains folks seem pretty on top of their game.